# java gui boxlayout question

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, boxlayout

I am working on a java gui application hard coding without any netbeans help.  I am using the box layout for my gui.  My question is simple from what I see online boxlayout should stack elements on top of each other.  However, I have a textarea(x,y) a toggle button and another textarea(x,y) when this is displayed there is a gap between my first text area and the toggle button and a gap between the toggle button and the 2nd textarea.  Why are they not being stacked! 
Thanks,

Comment: You may wish to post a very small compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your problem, an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Please check the link out as it is very helpful for both you and us.  Also, are you using the `BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS` as the second parameter of your BoxLayout constructor call? Luck!

Comment: BoxLayout.Y_AXIS is the same as BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS, I believe, so that's not the problem. Again, I recommend an SSCCE, for example as shown below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of an SSCCE that tries to demonstrate your problem. Perhaps you can modify it to show us what's going on:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BoxLayoutEg {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JTextArea area1 = new JTextArea(10, 20);
      JToggleButton toggleBtn = new JToggleButton("Foo");
      JTextArea area2 = new JTextArea(10, 20);

      JPanel toggleBtnPanel = new JPanel();
      toggleBtnPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
      // toggleBtnPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
      toggleBtnPanel.add(toggleBtn);

      JPanel mainJPanel = new JPanel();
      mainJPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainJPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

      mainJPanel.add(new JScrollPane(area1));
      mainJPanel.add(toggleBtnPanel);
      mainJPanel.add(new JScrollPane(area2));

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mainJPanel);

   }
}
```